# Arithmetic overflow error for smallint--but the datatype is int?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, int, sqldatatypes

I have a stored procedure that inserts values into a table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSaveAddresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations]
   @idAddresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations INT    = NULL OUTPUT,
   @idLogin INT = -32768,
   @idAddress INT = NULL,
   @idLegalDescription INT = NULL,
   @idDetermination INT = NULL
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   SET ROWCOUNT 0
   SET XACT_ABORT ON

   BEGIN TRY
      /* Declare and initialize variables */
      DECLARE   @RC         INT,
                @TranCount  INT

      SELECT    
          @RC = 0,
          @TranCount = @@TRANCOUNT

      /* Insert record into Table #1] */
      IF @TranCount = 0 
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
      BEGIN
           INSERT INTO [TOD].[dbo].[Table#1](idAddress, idLegalDescription,
                                             idDetermination, UpdatedidLogin,
                                             UpdatedDate)
           VALUES(@idAddress, @idLegalDescription,
                  @idDetermination, @idLegalDescription, GETDATE())
     END

     IF @TranCount = 0 AND (XACT_STATE()) = 1 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    EXEC [TOD].[dbo].[spRethrowError]
    SET @RC = 1
END CATCH

SET NOCOUNT OFF
SET ROWCOUNT 0
RETURN @RC
GO
```

The structure of table #1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations]
(
    [idAddresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [idAddress] [int] NULL,
    [idLegalDescription] [int] NULL,
    [idDetermination] [int] NULL,
    [UpdatedidLogin] [smallint] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations_UpdatedidLogin]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pkAddresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([idAddresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] ASC)
) ON [DATA]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] WITH NOCHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations_Addresses] 
       FOREIGN KEY([idAddress])
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Addresses] ([idAddress])
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] 
      CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations_Addresses]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] WITH NOCHECK   
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations_Determinations]   
    FOREIGN KEY([idDetermination])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Determinations] ([idDetermination])
ON DELETE CASCADE
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] CHECK    CONSTRAINT [FK_Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations_Determinations]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations]  WITH NOCHECK   ADD  CONSTRAINT     [FK_Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations_LegalDescriptions] FOREIGN   KEY([idLegalDescription])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LegalDescriptions] ([idLegalDescription])
ON DELETE CASCADE
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations] CHECK    CONSTRAINT [FK_Addresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations_LegalDescriptions]
GO
```

The structure of the table causing the error:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LegalDescriptions](
[idLegalDescription] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[LotNumber] [varchar](15) NULL,
[BlockNumber] [varchar](15) NULL,
[SubDivision] [varchar](255) NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[InsertedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[SubDivisionPhase] [varchar](5) NULL,
[Township] [varchar](20) NULL,
[UpdatedidLogin] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_LegalDescriptions_UpdatedidLogin]  DEFAULT ((0)),
[InsertedIDLogin] [smallint] NULL,
[LegalDescription] [varchar](255) NULL,
[PinNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
[Range] [varchar](15) NULL,
[SectionLegalDescription] [varchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pkLegalDescriptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idLegalDescription] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [DATA]
) ON [DATA]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

The error I am receiving when I try to execute the stored procedure:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spRethrowError, Line 42
>   Error 220, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spSaveAddresses_LegalDescriptions_Determinations, Line 42
>   Message: Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 171922.

My question:

All data types for this column that throws the error [idLegalDescription] are `INT`, why is the `stored procedure` calling for a `smallint` data type? I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your column

```
 [UpdatedidLogin] [smallint]
```

Is populated by

```
@idLegalDescription                             INT
```

Comment: WOW! What a horrible typo. I knew it was something so simple. Crap, thank you! I'll accept this as the answer as soon as the time limit is up.